# How to scale html font size in Bootstrap 4 without breaking responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to scale a webpage the bootstrap 4 way (using html font-size and rem everywhere else) but it seems to break the responsive navbar's activation (i.e. it doesn't activate properly).

The actual problem is when you scale the view down, the responsive navbar is supposed to hide the menu options and provide the hamburger icon. However, if you scale the html font-size up, the responsive navbar does **not activate when the menu will be outside the viewport**. In the example provided, scale the view down with 22px font, and see how the menu goes to the next line. Then remove that CSS and scale the menu and it works just fine with 16px (default) font.

Any idea on how to remedy this problem, or am I doing responsive navbar and font scaling improperly?

https://jsfiddle.net/fsc6gpb8/3/

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive navbar</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Documentation regarding my example and responsive navbar: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#collapsible-content

Here is an image of the actual bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7uY4.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bootstrap v4, the navigation can be collapsed sooner or later using different css classes

eg:

- navbar-toggleable-xs
- navbar-toggleable-md
- navbar-toggleable-lg

With the button for the navigation:

- hidden-xs-up
- hidden-md-up
- hidden-lg-up

And of course you can use media queries to do that.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more explicit. Basically, if you resize your browser from desktop down to mobile width, the responsive navbar does not activate when the menu is about to go outside the viewport, because it does not calculate the new font-size into the width equation (I believe)

Comment: Hmm.. That's crazy I guess. Restart your browser, it may help.

Well, It's working for me http://puu.sh/qbSiV/ae8653ef7b.png

Comment: Here is exactly what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/bI9GWVN.png Note how the 22px html font-size jsfiddle, the responsive navbar does not activate, yet the menu is forced to the next line, meaning it would be outside the viewport, and thus should have activated. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Ohhh, I was looking with way smaller width.

Alright, you want to see hamburger menu as the menu reaches two lines, like in your given pictures?

Comment: The hamburger menu should activate before it reaches 2 lines, correct. Note, hamburger activating before 2 lines is the intended behaviour and works when html font-size is unchanged, but as in my example, when changed, the menu gets pushed down to 2 lines before it activates.

Comment: That's because Bootstrap is built to show hamburger menu only when it reaches 768 px (Bootstrap 4 may have different settings, that's for Bootstrap 3)

It's really hard to find a solution, but it can be done using Media queries

Comment: Found the temporary solution for this.

In bootstrap you can use different style classes to achieve that

eg. navbar-toggleable-md and for the button for the navigation: hidden-md-up

Comment: Note I tested and you need to use: navbar-toggleable-sm like in your jsfiddle, but in your comment you wrote: navbar-toggleable-md. This works perfectly, thank you, will give you the points, update your answer with this hack.

Comment: I don't use Bootstrap 4, you should have mentioned that you change the class. Anyway, awesome that everything works good now. I'll update my post.